# Subdomain setup nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain, virtualhost

My reviewer24.com.conf file looks like this:

```
server {
  server_name reviewer24.com www.reviewer24.com;

  access_log /home/nginx/domains/reviewer24.com/log/access.log combined buffer=32k;
  error_log /home/nginx/domains/reviewer24.com/log/error.log;

  root /home/nginx/domains/reviewer24.com/public;

  location / {

  # Enables directory listings when index file not found
  #autoindex  on;

  # Shows file listing times as local time
  #autoindex_localtime on;

  # Enable for vBulletin usage WITHOUT vbSEO installed
  #try_files         / /index.php;

  }

  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
  #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
}
```

I have created a folder "m" and placed a mobile version of the website in it. 
What rule should I add to this .conf file so when you go to: http://m.reviewer24.com it will display content from "m" folder?

Answer (score 3):

I would create a new .conf file specifically your mobile site, e.g. in `m.reviewer24.com.conf` with a new server block then reload your nginx config.

This way if you need to make specific changes to your subdomain configuration, it's easier to manage. Alternatively, you could append the new server block the into your existing config.

You'll also probably want to delegate where the mobile traffic access and error logs are :)

```
server {
  server_name m.reviewer24.com;

  access_log /home/nginx/domains/reviewer24.com/log/access.log combined buffer=32k;
  error_log /home/nginx/domains/reviewer24.com/log/error.log;

  root /home/nginx/domains/reviewer24.com/public/m;

  location / {

  # Enables directory listings when index file not found
  #autoindex  on;

  # Shows file listing times as local time
  #autoindex_localtime on;

  # Enable for vBulletin usage WITHOUT vbSEO installed
  #try_files         / /index.php;

  }

  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
  #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
}
```